# Hook into $wpdb

Tags: database, hooks, wpdb

Is there a way to hook into the WPDB instance ($wpdb)?

What i basically want, is to execute a own function BEFORE the desired query get's executed.

Is this possible?

## Additional question for comment to first answer:

```
    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "test WHERE type = %s and ip = %s", $type, $ip_full_log);
    $fetch = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
```

Would this parse the final query to my callback function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*query* - you will get sql as argument of the callback.

```
add_filter('query', 'some_callback_that_change_query');

function some_callback_that_change_query($sql){
    remove_filter('query', 'some_callback_that_change_query');
    // your banny wrote
    add_filter('query', 'some_callback_that_change_query');
    return $sql;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added a additional question to my original one. Please take a look at it. Many thanks!

Comment: didn't really understand your additional question. With *query*  filter you can hook to any query. Inside callback you can remove you hooked callback and set it after you proccess your code. is that you wanted?

Comment: I mean, do i have to use the query() function, or does this hook will also get called for the get_results() function, for example?

Comment: this is a filter-hook - its only to *change* almost every sql query. but use can use it to run your sql query.

Comment: Sadly that was not my question. I can excute querys with multiple functions. e.g. with query() and get_results(). Will this filter get called for each of them?

Comment: Yes. This filter 'hook' runnig each time you running any query...