# Alter a specific query on Wordpress

Tags: query, wpdb

I need to change a query of a plugin that is **not** the main query. The author did not put any filters.
I can see the query from

```
$wpdb->queries
```

Is there a way to access the specific query and replace what I need?
If you need further info I will gladly provide.
Thank you in advance.

**Edit**
As requested:

There is a class eg. MyClass
Inside there is a function eg myfunction

myfunction has

```
$event_obj = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

Can I alter $querystr ?

**EDIT #2**

I believe I am getting somewhere (after 4 hours).

```
add_filter('query', 'spyros_query');
function spyros_query($query) {

  if (strpos($query,'what_only_this_query_will_contain') !== false) {
    return false; // for testing purposes
  }

  return $query;
}
```

** EDIT #3 (the full query) **

http://pastebin.com/8zxTSdV8

Regards,

Spyros

Comment: When you ask question please provide full detail of the issue. No can help you if they don't see the problem. Edit your question and add in the code or any other information to help other understand your problem and help you.

Comment: How is $querystr built? Just looking at the line doesn't give much idea. Is $querystr directly inserted like  $querystr = "SELECT * FROM ........." or is it built in other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use the `query` filter hook

See [this WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152770/hook-into-wpdb)

Basically, you can do something like:

```
add_filter( 'query', 'your_filter_function' );

function your_filter_function($query_sql) {
    // do something to $query_sql
    return $query_sql;
}
```

This will get called for *every* query, so you'll need to test `$query_sql` to make sure it's the query you want.

Comment: You are right @anu. I was just thinking the same way. I believe I can find my way now. I will just do a str_replace if I can find the specific string in the query.

Comment: I am marking this as the correct answer. Thank you @anu for helping me see clear.

Comment: @Spyros no probs - good luck!